# How can I insert data from one table to another table after insert a data in first table?

Tags: mysql, t-sql

Please Help me,

How can I insert data from one table to another table **after insert a data** in first table?
I wrote a query but it has problem, It said "Unknown column 'test.ProjectNumber' ". should I define it first?
I want insert data to test.ProjectNumber from test2.PN
Please help me

Code:

```
    /**
 * Insert a record on another table
 */

// SQL statement parameters
$insert_table  = 'test2';    
$insert_fields = array(  
     'test2.PN' => 'test.ProjectNumber',
 );

// Insert record
$insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $insert_table
    . ' ('   . implode(', ', array_keys($insert_fields))   . ')'
    . ' VALUES ('    . implode(', ', array_values($insert_fields)) . ')';

sc_exec_sql($insert_sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is evaluates as follows:

```
INSERT INTO test2 ( test2.PN ) VALUES ( test.ProjectNumber );
```

This is not valid because `test.ProjectNumber` is not understood in this context.

I think what you need to do is two separate insert statements as follows:

```
-- assumes that the number has not been inserted into test2 yet, 
-- just insert the same value into both tables:
INSERT INTO test2 ( test2.PN ) 
VALUES ( somevalue );

INSERT INTO test ( test.ProjectNumber )
VALUES ( somevalue );
```

or if the first row has already been inserted (it's not clear form your question), you can select that value and insert it, but you need to be able to identify the row (I'm using `123`)

```
-- If test2 already contains the row you need to insert from
-- then you need to select that row to insert the new row in test
INSERT INTO test ( test.ProjectNumber )
SELECT test2.PN
FROM test2
WHERE test2.Id = someid;
```

Hopefully this helps - I haven't translated this into php for you, partly as an exercise for you, but partly because my php is pretty rusty...

Comment: Thanks For answer my friend. But i want insert data every time that I entered in first table. like trigger or store procedure. Do you know why test.ProjectNumber did not understood?

Comment: And also if I use the codes that you wrote, every time that i execute this code it will duplicate previous data